# Gernerate new cluster_uuid in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We´ve cloned **two VMWare instances** with ES (= two nodes in the same cluster) so that we can use them on another part of our network. I´ve set a new cluster name for both machines / nodes and everything works fine.

The only "problem" I see is, that the **new machines / nodes have the same cluster_uuid** as the orignal ones (although they have a different cluster_name). Can this become an issue? And if so - can I regenerate the uuid for the new cluster?

Thanks & BR

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove (or just rename) `_state` directory with metadata under `/<path.data>/<cluster.name>/nodes/0`, Elasticsearch will recreate it on next startup with new random uuid. Indices will be imported, but transient & persistent settings, mappings, etc will be lost.

Comment: I tried it, did not work. It did how ever create a new _state folder